# Design using only D FF a counter that goes 0->2->1->5->7

Tags: flipflop, counter

Have this as an exercise in my logic design textbook. I know how to do this with additional logic, but the challenge comes from only having D flip-flops available. I assume there are at least 3 of them for the state, but maybe some additional ones for making the loop? I'm also looking for a way to logically deduct the solution to this problem.

Edit: The text says: "Design a counter following a counting loop of 0->2->1->5->7 using only D flipflops and wires."

Comment: sho-sho-sho-show us us us us your att-att-attempt!

Comment: only flip flops?

Comment: Can you share the actual text of the problem you're given? Are you sure it says DFF's are the only parts available? Or could it mean DFF's are the only kind of flip-flop or latch available, but other logic could be available? Do your DFF's have complementary outputs?

Comment: General way would be to have a regular counter and then combinatoric network to map the "usual" numbers into the "unusual" ones.

Comment: Write out 0, 2, 1, 5, 7 in binary. Notice a pattern?

Comment: You only need 3 flip-flops to achieve those states. 2 1N4148 diodes or a AND gate for the value '5'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework needs a solution in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ONLY DFF's I would use 15 DFFs and make three loops of five. (Output goes back to input) with preset values.
Thus the first loop is preset to 00111 (ls bit), second 01001 (middle bit), third 00011 (ms bit).

---

Elaboration:
If you write the sequence of numbers in binary you get:

```
   000
   010
   001
   101
   111
```

You then take a column and convert that to 5 DFFs in a row but you connect the output of the last one to the input of the first one. If you clock those DFF's the pattern will go round in a circle.

Using some sort of reset you can set or clear the DFF's to the preset values of a column. If you clock all 15 DFF's the patterns will rotate. If you take any three 'adjacent' DFFs you will see the sequence come by.

```
1 -> 1 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0  => this is
1 -> 0 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0  => where your
1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 0 -> 0  => numbers appear
```

In the 'diagram' above the sequence appears only once.
To repeat it you loop the output back to the input

```
+-> 1 -> 1 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -+  => this is
+-> 1 -> 0 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -+  => where your
+-> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 0 -> 0 -+  => numbers appear
|                          |
+----------<-------<-------+
```

It may not be elegant as it is brute force. But it works and you can use it for any pattern. I would never do it like this in real life unless it is not too big and has to run at e.g. 10GHz.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am not familiar with this method. Why 5 flip flops?

Comment: 15 flip-flops..lol cute

Comment: That might be the answer though, if he cant use gates and they are SR-D-Types.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to deal with a problem like this.

1. Use a regular binary counter or shift register and decode the outputs from that to generate the bits of the numbers you want the counter to present.

[image]

2. Figure out the logic of the count sequence to know when to present a 1 or a 0 to each latch based on the value of the previous state.

[image]

The first method presents a less synchronised output since the ripple through the decoding logic can delay some bits more than others so a resynchronizing latch on the output is not uncommon.

Which way is better will depend on the complexity of the data sequence and how important the synchronism is.

[Simulator](http://simulator.io/board/q7zOhUpufX/3)

But if you really can only use flip-flops...